# What do the flashing rates on an Elster REX2 electric meter signify?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, meter

Our electric service (USA) is metered with an Elster REX2 digital smart meter. There is a main display area that cycles through some lines of information, most importantly the total energy used. Below the main display is a double-headed arrow made of three elements (it looks something like `◀︎ ■ ▶︎`). The arrow flashes slowly or quickly to indicate direction and rate of energy flow—the arrowhead flashes on and off relatively quickly, and the central box flashes less often.

I'm wondering what *exactly* those flashes indicate. Is the arrowhead one watt and the central box ten? Or is it ten and fifty? Fifty and 200?

Comment: Those meter are programmable and the displays can be changed. Contact your power company and ask for the information.

Comment: Thanks @jack but after finding the info on these meters and only getting down votes , I Can’t give a upvote fore a good comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual the arrow box arrow are real energy indicators
Of 3.2 Rex meter tech manual

They pulse at a rate proportional to the rate of consumption.
Each square pulse indicates 1kh.  each change of state on to off indicates 1/2kh.

The arrow toggles for each Ke
Left arrow energy received
Right arrow indicates energy delivered.
It said see table 2-1 for ke values per meter form.
Form 1s, 2s, 12s.   ke.1 kh1.0
Form 3s, 4s      ke.  0.01 HK 1.0

So it depends on the meter form
The different forms are the class meter 20, 200, 320 2 wire or 3 wire single phase and if there is a disconnect link.

Comment: I'm not looking at it but I believe it's a 200-class meter, form is 2s. The service is 240V split-phase (two phases).

What does "kh" stand for, do you know?

Comment: Kh stands for kilo what hours, or 1000 watts for an hour is 1 Kh . In old light bulb terms a 100w lightbulb x10 turned on for 1 hour is 1 Kh ,today it takes a lot of lights if LED’s to produce the same power usage for light. But turn an electric oven on and watch the meter spin, same with electric water heaters while they are heating the water.  code requires water heaters to be rated at 5000 watts so if a water heater was heating at full power for an hour you could see it could consume 5kw per hour of use , lucky we don’t have the hot water running all the time but I hope this example helps.

Comment: I know what kilowatt-hours are but I'm used to seeing "kWh" rather than "kh", that's why I asked. And I'm 100% certain that the flashes are too fast to be any appreciable fraction of a kilowatt-hour. Probably like @JACK said the meters are customized by the utility company.

Comment: I am not sure of why the down votes as I have provided all the info easily found online with the available information, not quite customized meters as I do agree with jack for some meters , but after trying to answer after finding on line info getting down votes I can do no better as I provided references. No acceptance of an answer and only down votes good luck.

Comment: Kh is a watt hour constant and is equal to the number of watt hours per pulse or rotation of the meter disk. You know I didn't DV.  You got 99% right+1

Comment: @randomhead Kh is a watt hour constant and is equal to the number of watt hours per pulse or rotation of the meter disk.

Comment: @JACK I think I understand now, the central box flash is one "energy unit" and the arrowhead flash is 0.5 "energy unit"—and I need to contact the utility company, as you said, to ask what the unit they're actually using is. Is that correct?

Comment: @EdBeal you said the info in your post was easily finable online but I must not have been searching right because I wasn't able to find anything like that. Do you have a link you can post? I would be interested in seeing Table 2-1.

Comment: @randomhead  The Kh is usually printed on the meter (mine is 10.0 on a smart meter and was 7.2 on my old disk meter). It's how many watt hours are used per pulse. If you time the number of pulses in seconds,  the watts you're using = (3600*pulses*Kh) / time (in seconds) = watts.  Keep in mind, it's watts, not kilowatts.

Comment: I just searched for Rex 2 users manual.

Comment: Rex 2 smart meter users manual.  the result with rx9a was the most complete with how the RF reader system worked.

Comment: @EdBeal, I must ask again if you **have a link** to the document you found so easily. I must be searching poorly, because I cannot find the user's manual for the REX2, only the installation manual.

Answer (score 2):

From the [technical manual for the A3 ALPHA](http://guggenmossales.com/documents/A3MeterTM42-2190BUSVersion.pdf), a similar Elster meter:

> The real energy indicators blink at a rate proportional to kWh consumption. The center square indicator will blink to indicate pulses of K<sub>h</sub>. Each square indicator pulse (turns on and off) indicates 1 K<sub>h</sub>. A single transition (on–to–off or off–to–on) indicates 1⁄2 K<sub>h</sub>. The left and right arrows blink at a faster rate representing K<sub>e</sub>. Each arrow pulse (turns on and off) indicates 1/12 K<sub>h</sub> energy measurement. This means that a single transition of an arrow pulse (off–to–on, or on–to–off) represents 1/24 K<sub>h</sub>. The left and right arrows indicate energy being either received or delivered, respectively.

K<sub>h</sub> should be printed on the front of the meter; on mine, it's 7.2.

So each on-off-on cycle of the right arrow of my meter means my house used (7.2 Wh)/12 = 0.6 Wh of energy, and each on-off-on cycle of the square means 7.2 Wh.

To measure current power, you'd take a stopwatch and time one of those transitions.  e.g. I just measured 20 seconds for half a cycle of the square, so that's

7.6/2 Wh × (3600 sec/hr ÷ 20 sec)
= 3.6 Wh × 180 h<sup>–1</sup>
= 648 watts.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Despite what Ed Beal said, it seems very difficult to find a PDF of the actual user/technical manual for the REX2; the only thing I've been able to find is the installation manual. I would like to see a link to the REX2 manual before accepting this answer, to know the actual relation between K_h and the flash rates.